# starting with regexes

Tags: javascript, regex

*disclaimer: entirely new to regexes*

I am trying to write a simple regex to validate email strings like this:

```
/^\w+@\w+\.\w{1,4}/.test(emailstring);
```

The above should return false for = a@d.abcde but true for a@d.abcd. I need the extension to be limited to four characters {1,4}. But it always returns true for any length of tld extension. What's wrong in the above expression?

Comment: Side note: top level domains are not restricted to four characters anyway.

Comment: determine end of string $

Comment: As usual, add *both* anchors: `/^\w+@\w+\.\w{1,4}$/`

Comment: Since the issue is typical and highly frequent, I suggest that you do the basic exercises at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com). You will get the grasp of regex basics and will be able to handle such issues by yourself. [Lesson 10](http://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end) will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the end-of-line anchor (`$`):

```
/^\w+@\w+\.\w{1,4}$/.test(emailstring);
```